# How to pass a delimited txt file to a function that takes constant char *?

Tags: c++, c

I have an API function that takes constant char * as an input. I have to create a delimited text file which is the input of the function like:

```
193.875 0.0     0.0     2
193.876 0.0     0.0     2
193.877 0.0     0.0     2
193.878 0.0     0.0     2
193.879 0.0     0.0     2
193.880 0.0     0.0     2
193.881 0.0     0.0     2
```

the support guy of the software told me that I can create and save every line of this file by using *sprintf()* so I used it like:

```
sprintf(wsp,"%.3f\t0.0\t0.0\t%d\n", start_freq, z);
```

and after putting this line in loop I saved every created wsp in an array of string:

```
for (int j = 0; j < start; j++){

sprintf(wsp,"%.3f\t0.0\t0.0\t%d\n", start_freq, z);
start_freq = start_freq + 0.001;
wspfile[j] = wsp;

}
```

now I have a file with the required format but comes in array of string. My question is after creating the array how can I pass this array as a **constant char *** or how can I convert it to **constant char ***

Comment: Could it be that you have to pass the **filename** to the function?

Comment: Open the file, determine it's size, read it in a dynamically allocated `char` buffer of file's size and pass the adress of this buffer to your function. `char*` is implicitly convertible to `const char*`.

Comment: Added c tag, as there isn't much c++ in your question :)

Comment: @jrok what if I don't want to save wspfile. I mean wspfile is just an array not a saved file. How can I do that then?

Comment: I see, I misread your question.

Comment: Note the bug: `wspfile[j] = wsp;` will copy the *pointer*, not the *content*. As wsp is reused during the next iteration, the content will be overwritten with the next line. After the for loop, you'll have an array where all lines have the same content.

Comment: @Sjoerd Are you sure about that? cuz last time I checked the array didn't have the same content or maybe I'm wrong. but right now I get this "debug assertion failed" when I want to call sprintf. I'm using VS2010 express. any idea what's wrong? this is driving me crazy :|

Comment: @Fanttazio You say "text file" and "txt file" in your question. But there doesn't appear to be a text file. Do you mean "array of text"? Can you post the prototype of the function you have to call?

Comment: @Scooter I edited my post. It's just a text content or as you said array of text. The function prototype is " ws_load_profile (const char * name, const char * profiletext) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make wspFile an std::string instead of an array.  Then instead of

```
wspFile[j]=wsp;
```

you would have

```
wspFile+=wsp;
```

Then to get the const char* version you would call

```
wspFile.c_str();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. I used your approach and I got results. Although I feel my code is not best approach and has lots of stupid mistakes, at least I can talk to my device now!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you know the size of your data upfront, so you could do it like this:

```
std::vector<char> wspfile(start * wsp_max_length);
// C-ish way:
/* char* wspfile = (char*) malloc(start * wsp_max_length) */

for (int j = 0; j < start; j++) {
    sprintf(wsp + (wsp_max_length * j), "%.3f\t0.0\t0.0\t%d\n", start_freq, z);
    start_freq = start_freq + 0.001;
}

your_API_func(&wspfile[0]);
```

In more C++ like fashion:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>  // for setprecision()

std::vector<char> wspfile;
double start_freq = 193.875;

for (int j = 0; j < start; ++j, start_freq += 0.0001) {

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::setprecision(3)
        << start_freq
        << "\t0.0\t0.0\t"
        << z << "\n\0";  // your version with sprintf adds '\0', too,
                         // although I'm pretty sure you don't want it

    std::string wsp = oss.str();
    wspfile.insert(wspfile.end(), wsp.begin(), wsp.end());
}

your_API_func(&wspfile[0]);
```

Comment: I tried your c++ approach but I encounter debug assertion failed and it shows that it's in vector part and it points here: #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
  if (size() <= _Pos)
   { // report error
   _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
   _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
   }

Comment: Your accesing the vector out of bounds. Without code, I can't help much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have not misunderstood your question. I start assuming I have an array of N `char*`, namely `wspfile[]`, right? Now, I want to convert this array to a single string:

```
char *join(char **strings, int N)
{
    //Step 1: find out the total amount of memory we need
    int i, total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        total += strlen(strings[i]);
    }

    //Step 2. Allocate resulting string.
    char *str = malloc(total + 1); //Alloc 1 more byte for end \0

    //Step 3. Join strings.
    char *dst = str;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        char *src = strings[i];
        while(*src) *dst++ = *src++;
    }
    *dst = 0; //end \0
    return str; //don't forget to free(str) !
}
```

Then, in your code:

```
char *s = join(wspfile, N);
/* do whatever with `s`*/
free(s);
```

Comment: You misread my post. I actually wanted to create an array of string like: string content [1024], but I changed my approach now. I applied Dan's approach instead of creating an array of string. it seems easier but maybe I won't have enough flexibility if I want to change the code later!